# Image ScaleAspectFit empty space

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm trying to add pictures in a vertical manner using three imageViews. I want them to maintain aspect ratios, however, every time I add them to the view using ScaleAspectFit, there is a lot of empty space above and below the imageViews due to the aspect ratio being maintained. [Here is the picture of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi2Bb.png). The blue is the imageView, and as you can see, it is much taller than the actual picture. I just don't know how I would go about making the imageView only as tall as the actual image. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: this probem is improved if you add this imageview to a uiview and then move the uiview around the window to where you want it to be, so UIView * ss  ... ss .... and UIImageView * gg ... ss addSubView:gg

Comment: also, you should probably println the image height and width to see if it's an image problem of some sort, sometimes you'd be surprised to see a whacky size, when you find the size, then you can set the height and width of the UIImageView to the size and width of the image itself very easily

Comment: I've tried setting the height of the uiImageView to the height of the image that I am adding to it but it doesn't change. It's like the height of the image is including all of that empty space.

Comment: It's okay, the way I do things is in a very non standard way, but uses UI elements to their max capacity. I'd show code but it's likely to confuse this issue even more. The point is, first check the size and height of the image, and if it turns out the image is the size you expect then just set the frame of the UIIMageView to that size

Comment: No, no, no, when you set the size and such based on the REAL size of the image, DON'T set a content mode, you won't need it then

Comment: in ObjC CGRectMake(0,0,[UIImage imageNamed:@"cats"].size.width, [UIImage imageNamed:@"cats"].size.height), this is basically the same thing in Swift, Im sure you get it

Comment: Changing the frame doesn't change anything. Did something similar with the answer given below and [nothing changed](http://i.imgur.com/LrkRwCE.png).

Comment: the big qustion is this then, what is the value of the height and width of that picture in you debugger? Print out the height and width in your debugger .

Comment: The image added to the imageView and the imageView are the same dimensions [according to the debugger](http://i.imgur.com/TSS0ojR.jpg).

Comment: k, so that's a problem, why is there a blue background? what sort of image resizing method are you using? besides this one "onscreenpointsizeofimageinimageview"

Comment: i mean problem as in, that's a very big image for IOS, since those dimensions are in POINTS not pixels, and, for example, the Iphone 6+ screen is only 414 x 736, so your image there is LARGER than the largest iphoen screen

Comment: and furthermore, I bet if you multiplied the height and width by lets say 25% then the image would shrink accordingly and give you an indication of what's wrong

Comment: I am using the blue background just so I can debug. I wanna see how large the imageView is after adding the image, so I use the blue background just to see it during debugging right now. I actually removed that method, it was not doing anything. So all I'm using is [this](https://gist.github.com/nmcdonaldd/588d4c9589789c2f2e42) and setting the mode to .ScaleAspectFit.

Comment: so, this CGRectMake(0,0,[UIImage imageNamed:@"cats"].size.width, [UIImage imageNamed:@"cats"].size.height), , becomes this CGRectMake(0,0,[UIImage imageNamed:@"cats"].size.width*0.5, [UIImage imageNamed:@"cats"].size.height*0.5) .. see what happens to the image now

Comment: Right, so I understand that I can simply multiply it by an arbitrary amount to reduce the size, however, I want it to be absolutely the size of the image height.

Comment: in addition, the image size you are using is the RAW image size straight from the camera, that's a HUGE image using this full image this way, you should resize it proportionally to the size you want in order for it to fit correclty where you want it

Comment: you have to downscale that thing to something reasonable using Image IO

Comment: I have a method that uses image IO and is the advanced NO MEMORY loading method, but it's in objective C and it would be sort of hard to translate it, unless you know how to trnslate over, but this would surely help you

Comment: Okay so after implementing that above, nothing changes visually, but the debugger says the heigh and the width are half of the image size. But, again, the imageView hasn't changed visually. Looks the exact same as before.

Comment: yep that sucks, okay so then give us an idea of where you want the image to appear on the screen, you said three iamgeviews one on top of the other right?

Comment: Exactly, so I just want them to be one after another vertically.

Comment: k, give me a sec, I know what you are expeirencing and it's rough to do this through the internets because I've been there before, I'll get the solution to you, but its going to take a minute. If you find it before I do then perfect, but i'll post as soon as I have something that will fall in line what what you are doing, I can tell from your code that you know HOW to code so this makes it easier for me.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm still stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the size of imageview from image try this it might help you.

```
UIImage *img = _myImageView.image;
    _myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(_myImageView.frame.origin.x, _myImageView.frame.origin.y, img.size.width, img.size.height);
```

Comment: you could not try this code in viewDidLoad method.Try in this method -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{UIImage *img = _myImageView.image;
    _myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(_myImageView.frame.origin.x, _myImageView.frame.origin.y, img.size.width, img.size.height);}

Comment: This is happening after viewDidLoad. If you look, theres a library and camera button at the bottom of the controller that I use for the user to add pictures.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean^

Comment: Okay [here it is](https://gist.github.com/nmcdonaldd/588d4c9589789c2f2e42). Thanks so much so far Vishnuvardhan.

Comment: Hey just add below line to the image view and try.I think it is due to the auto layout constraints it is not resizing.            myImageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)

Comment: When I do that, I get an error about not being able to simultaneously satisfy all constraints. Nothing changes either.